# Getting address of first passed variadic argument

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdarg.h>

template<typename... Args> 
void Func(Args... args)
{
// WANT: Get the address of the first argument

// TRIED:
// va_list vargs = (char*)&(args);
// va_list vargs = (char*)&(args)...;
// va_list vargs = (char*)&(args...);

// GOT:
// 'args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
}
```

I'm writing a function that accepts N arguments and does something with all of them. And for that I want to grab the address of the first element of the variadic argument list.

After that, to my knowledge the `va_arg` macro dereferences the pointer and shifts `va_list` type object with the size of assumed type

Edit: I could do probably something like this:

```
template<typename... Args> 
void Func(int arg1, Args... args)
{
// Code
}
```

But, it would result in more lines of code which I don't want.

Comment: `<stdarg.h>` is a very different feature that has no relation to C++ variadic templates.

Comment: all described in detail here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler would be to split argument in signature:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts> 
void Func(T arg, Ts... args)
{
// WANT: Get the address of the first argument
    T* p = &arg;
}
```

else

```
template <typename... Ts> 
void Func(Ts... args)
{
// WANT: Get the address of the first argument
    auto* p = std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(&args...));
}
```